# Does the index become empty or match the tracked files of the newly pointed commit, after resetting hard?

Tags: git, indexing, staging

We know that, when we switch branch, the index content is reset to the commit referenced by the branch we just switched to. **(git checkout *branch_name*)**

But, what about this command?

**git reset HEAD~1 --hard**

Surely, it undoes the current commit, moves to the previous commit, and does not preserve the current commit's work tree and index. But, does it make the index **empty** or does it fill the index with the information of files tracked in an old commit that we moved to, like in the case of **"git checkout branch_name"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It—`git reset`, with appropriate flags—fills the index from the commit to which you are re-setting.

Git makes this confusing because of the spelling of `--allow-empty` and `--keep-empty` flags (`git commit`, `git rebase`, and the like): these make it *sound like* the index is empty, when in fact the index simply matches the commit.  It's the *diff* that's empty.

Note that `git reset` resets the index (to match the commit) with both `--hard` and the default `--mixed`.  Using `--soft` suppresses the index-reset.